# R create sequence in dplyr by id beginning with zero

Tags: r, dplyr, seq

I'm looking for the cleanest way to create a sequence beginning with zero by id in a dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame (id=rep(1:10,each=10))
```

If I wanted to start sequence at 1 the following would do:

```
library(dplyr)
df<-df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(start = 1:n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

but starting at 0 doesn't work because it creates an extra number (0-10 compared to 1-10) so I need to add an extra row, is there a way to do this all in one step, perhaps using `dplyr`? There is obviously a number of work arounds such as creating another dataset and appending it to the original.

```
df1 <- data.frame (id=1:10,
                  start=0)
new<-rbind(df,df1)
```

That just seems a bit awkward and not that tidy. I know you can use rbind in dplyr but not sure how to incorporate everything in one step especially if you had other non-timing varying variables you just wanted to copy over into the new row. Interested to see suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `complete()` from the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(start = 1:n()) %>%
  complete(start = c(0:10)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which yields

```
# A tibble: 110 x 2
      id start
   <int> <int>
 1     1     0
 2     1     1
 3     1     2
 4     1     3
 5     1     4
 6     1     5
 7     1     6
 8     1     7
 9     1     8
10     1     9
# ... with 100 more rows
```